# Control many comboboxes with one method comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, winforms

For example, I have 100 comboboxes and need to update a particular combobox when it's selected a new index. How can I use only one method to catch the event when there is a combobox set a new value?

Comment: You can assign the same SelectedIndexChanged event to all of the combo boxes, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Create only one event handler `ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged`, and subscribe all the combo boxes to this event:

```
combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
combobox2.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
combobox3.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
combobox4.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
//and so on
```

The event handler code:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //now "sender" is the reference to the combo box raised the event
    //so just cast it
    ComboBox combobox = sender as ComboBox;

    //now access it as you want
}
```